# R: precipitation data seasonal (DJFM) sums for each station

Tags: r

I have a data.frame "n_com", which includes columns for "year" (1951-2010), "month" (1,2,3,12) and 81 further value-columns for monthly precipitation sums of 81 weather-stations.

```css
 Jahr Monat 12_NS_Monat 13 NS Monat 14 NS Monat 15 NS Monat 16 NS Monat
1 1951     1         397        2045        1447        2666         236
2 1951     2         528        1043         464        1397         202
3 1951     3         819         480         953        1634         665
4 1951    12         363         252         881         610         350
5 1952     1         391         530         557        1321         339
6 1952     2         683         684         920        1125         805
```

Now, I need the seasonal sums for each year for the months december, january, february and march (DJFM) for each station. But the seasonal sums should include the information of the december-month of the previous year, while the informations about the other months should come from the current year.
(e.g.: seasonal sum of 1956 which includes december-data of 1955, while the other months are from 1956)

Finally, I want a data.frame with the following columns: "year", "station 1", "station 2" and so on..

It seems, that the function "dm2seasonal" of the package "hydroTSM" is the right for me to create seasonal sums. My problem is, that "hydroTSM" needs special formation of the data.frame (data in long format), but my data.frame is in wide-format. Can anayone help me formatting my data for the package "hydroTSM" or has got another solution to create seasonal sums?

greetz from Germany

Answer (score 0):

More a hack than a solution,  but you could probably just add 1 to the 'year'  column for all rows with month = 12 :

`n_com$yeartemp = n_com$year
n_com$yeartemp[n_com$month == 12]  = n_com$year[n_com$month == 12] + 1`

To change column names,  see 'names`.

Then,  to change to long format you can use `melt` in `reshape2` package,  using yeartemp as id variable.

Hth.

Hth.